# Use Zen grids with Views

Tags: theming

We are using Zen 7.x-5.x with responsive settings and I want to create a grid for some items. That is responsive and adaptive so first the grid is 3 items and then when the viewport gets narrower there is 2 or one.

How can I use Zen grids with Views is there an automatic way of specifying a n column(s) responsive grid out of views? Is there a connection or are there any specific classes I can use in my views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://zengrids.com/help/) there are lot of examples how to make a grid with 3 items etc. About views and zen grids, I do not think that there is such a module because if you are use zen grids you use the grid for the entire site, if you need to specify grid for some items you can use `mix-ins` [here](http://zengrids.com/help/#mixins) you can read about them.

> **zen-nested-container()** Apply this to any grid item that is also a grid
>   container element for a nested grid. It must be applied after the
>   zen-grid-item() mixin is applied. This mixin ensures the container
>   does not have a gutter since the nested grid items will have their own
>   gutters.

Answer (score 4):

You can create grids inside the main container or others.

You can look at these 2 modules for views and grids:

Views Responsive Grids

Views Column Class

Then you only need to create your own grid for that view. And of course you can select n columns with nth-child

For example: A view with Views Responsive Grids of 3 columns and N rows

```
  .your-view-class {
  $zen-column-count:  3;
  @include zen-grid-container();
  div:nth-child(n+1) {
    .views-column-1 { @include zen-clear(); @include zen-grid-item(1, 1);}
    .views-column-2 { @include zen-grid-item(1, 2);}
    .views-column-3 { @include zen-grid-item(1, 3);}
  }

}
```